# How to use hover with a link id and a div id

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a mega menu with `html` and `css`. The dropdown has 2 columns, and I am trying to show different outputs on the right when I hover a link from the left column.

Here is my HTML code:

```css
.column-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

#firstleft:hover #first {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-left">
  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <a id="firstleft" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="first" class="column-right">
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

So when I hover the first link, the div would appear.

Comment: HI, you need to be way more specific then that. "show different outputs" is very vague and broad. However, you cant use `:hover` to change other elements that are not children of the element that you hover. For that you would need JS with `onmouseover` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cascading** Style Sheets, which means that CSS can't target parent selectors as it always executes styles down the DOM Tree.

Fortunately, there's a very easy Javascript fix that requires very little code:

```js
const hoverlink = document.querySelector('#firstleft')
const column_right = document.querySelector('#first')
// Show column
hoverlink.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  column_right.style.visibility = 'visible';
})
column_right.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  column_right.style.visibility = 'visible';
})
// Hide column
hoverlink.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  column_right.style.visibility = 'hidden';
})
column_right.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  column_right.style.visibility = 'hidden';
})
```

```css
.column-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-left">
  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <a id="firstleft" href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="first" class="column-right">
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

You can even make this more efficient by implementing two functions that execute on mouse events by hardcoding the rules into your HTML. I don't really recommend this way as it requires putting extra attributes (which isn't a problem, I just like to keep it clean) in your HTML, but this question was about a CSS explanation so I thought I'd post the simplest solution.

```html
<div class="column-left">
  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <a id="firstleft" href="#" onmouseover="showColumn()" onmouseout="hideColumn()">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="first" class="column-right" onmouseover="showColumn()" onmouseout="hideColumn()">
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

What if you want to show different content for specific links?

```js
const column_right = document.querySelector('#first')

function showContent(content) {
  var content = document.querySelector(`#${content}`);
  column_right.style.visibility = 'visible';
  content.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function hideContent(content) {
  var content = document.querySelector(`#${content}`);
  column_right.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  content.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```css
.column-right {
  visibility: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}
.column-right a {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-left">
  <h3>Category 1</h3>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="showContent('content1')" onmouseout="hideContent('content1')">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="showContent('content2')" onmouseout="hideContent('content2')">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
<div id="first" class="column-right">
  <h3>Category 2</h3>
  <a href="#" id="content1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="content2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was wondering if the JS could be done more general, because I have to do this with a lot of content, and it would not be okay to use the same code over and over.

Comment: If you choose the hardcoded in HTML route (my second method), you can pass in parameters through the brackets. The parameters you would pass in would likely be the id of the content you are trying to show. I'll edit my post to show an example.

Comment: Your welcome, if you feel that this helped, please consider accepting the answer by marking it as correct.

Comment: In the right side (the one showing when I hover) I have a table with <a> elements. In the first answer you gave me, I was able to access the elements on the right side, but in the second, I can't (because of the mouseout). Is there a solution where I can access the elements on the right?

Comment: I was thinking using :active on :hover, but I wasn't able to do it

Comment: Yeah, it should be the same as the first example where you add the same `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` behaviour on the content you choose and pass in the applicable parameters.